# PHP to merge PDFs via drag and drop

Tags: php, pdf, drag-and-drop, merge

I need a way to integrate these two functions. A solid click and drag [example of click and drag](http://skfox.com/jqExamples/SortableSelectable.html)
And PDFMerger [PDFMerger](http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/)

Im using PDFMerger and it works great

```
<?php
```

include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('testFile5.pdf', 'all')
    ->addPDF('testFile57.pdf', 'all')

```
->merge('download', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
?>
```

It combines 2 pdfs easily.
The problem is that I need to combine these two functions.
I need the user to be able to select which pdfs they want to combine and I would love do this VIA drag and drop such as the link above.
Can anyone give me a nudge in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to post data to your php script. In your jQuery example you have that field with comma seperated values which is usually hidden. Make sure that is inside a form. Then you just post the form with a submit button.

I'm sure you can write html code by yourself and php script should look something like that:

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';
$files = explode(",", $_POST['postOrder']); //or your name of the field

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $pdf->addPDF($file, 'all') 
}

$pdf->merge('download', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
?>
```

Of course you need to do more checking to ensure safety.

Comment: Im going to give it a shot although Im a hardcore noob with PHP.

Comment: Im getting an error maybe you could help me with here is the page [page here](http://www.cintascsr.com/test_site/pdf_creator/)

Comment: Did you make a form with the right fields and post it? Use `print_r($_POST)` to check if there are any files. You are getting an exception because the `$file` is empty.

Comment: I think Im doing it correctly [SEE IT HERE](http://www.cintascsr.com/test_site/pdf_creator/) I hate being such a bother.  Would I add in the form like this  <form method="post" action="print_r($_POST)"> ?  Any idea how to get $file to work correctly?  Im sorry to keep bothering you.

Comment: Action must be a php file with your script.